# xPath to get values from table

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

I am just getting started with XPath and am fiddling around with how to correctly traverse table elements to find the td values in a tr.  I am trying to only echo out the sibling values of the node .  My table, for example:

```
<table class="123">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td id="myYear">Year</td>
            <td>2001</td>
            <td>2002</td>
            <td>2003</td>
        </tr> 
        <tr>
            <td id="myScores">Scores</td>
            <td>82</td>
            <td>87</td>
            <td>94</td>
        </tr> 
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My php code is as follows:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;       
$dom->loadHTML($content);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$myYear = $xpath->query('//table[@class="123"]/tbody/tr/td[@id="myYear"]');

foreach ($myYear as $year) {
    echo $year->nodeValue; //returns Year
    echo "<br>";

    $siblings = $year->nextSibling;

    foreach ($siblings as $value) {
        echo $value->nodeValue;
    }
}
```

In the above example, the output is "Year" but I am not getting any output for the three sibling values of "myScores" for example 82,87,94.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

Some self-learning going on here!  I simply used following-sibling like so:

```
$myYear = $xpath->query('//table[@class="123"]/tbody/tr/td[@id="myYear"]/following-sibling::*');

foreach ($myYear as $year) {
    echo $year->nodeValue; //returns Year
    echo "<br>";
}
```